# Problema al parsear datos de un DateRangePicker

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Tengo un daterangepicker:

```
$( function() {
$( 'input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    regional: 'es',
    locale:{
      "fromLabel": "From",
      "toLabel": "To",
      "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
      "daysOfWeek": ["Lun","Mar","Mie","Jue","Vie","Sa","Dom"],
      "monthNames": ["Enero","Febrero", "Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"],
      applyLabel: 'Guardar',
      cancelLabel: 'Limpiar',
      monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
      dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
    }
});
$('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
});
$('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(this).val('');
}); 
  });
  </script>
```

El cual, despues en el metodo del controlador, recibo la fecha correctamente:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'type' => 'required',
        'observations' => 'required',
        'datefilter' => 'required',
    ]);

    $dep =\DB::table('users')->select('users.area_id')
        ->where(['users.id' => $request->user_id])
        ->get(); 

     //parse dates
    $date  = explode('-',$request['datefilter']);

    $dateFrom = date("dd-mm-yyyy",strtotime( $date[0]));
    $dateTo = date("dd-mm-yyyy",strtotime($date[1]));

    $vacation = new Vacation();
    $vacation -> user_id = $request['user_id'];
    $vacation -> type = $request['type'];
    $vacation -> observations = $request['observations'];
    $vacation -> area_id = $dep[0]->area_id;
    $vacation -> date_from = date("y-m-d", strtotime($dateFrom));
    $vacation -> date_to = date("y-m-d", strtotime( $dateTo ));
    //$vacation -> daysTaken = $daysTaken;

dd($date[0]->format('Y-m-d'));

$guardadas = \DB::table('vacations')->where(function($q) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
        // ambas dentro del rango/periodo
                $q->where('date_from', '>=', $dateFrom)
                  ->where('date_to', '<=', $dateTo);
        })->orWhere(function($q) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
        // fin desborda rango/periodo pero inicio dentro rango/periodo
                $q->where('date_from', '>=', $dateFrom)
                  ->where('date_to', '>', $dateTo);
        })->orWhere(function($q) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
        // inicio desborda rango/periodo pero fin dentro de rango/periodo
            $q->where('date_from', '<', $dateFrom)
              ->where('date_to', '<=', $dateTo);
        })->orWhere(function($q) use ($dateFrom, $dateTo) {
        // inicio y fin desbordan el rango/periodo
            $q->where('date_from', '<', $dateFrom)
              ->where('date_to', '>', $dateTo);
        })// otras condiciones
        ->get();

        //dd($guardadas);

        if($vacation->date_from != $guardadas[0]->date_from and $vacation->date_to != $guardadas[0]->date_to||
           $vacation->area_id != $guardadas[0]->area_id){

           $vacation->save();

            $data = request()->all();

           return back()->with('success','Vacaciones Solicitadas correctamente');

        }else{
            return back()->with('error','Fechas no disponibles');
        }

        return back();
    }
```

Mi problema viene a la hora de intentar parsear las fechas para hacer la diferencia de días, para saber por ejemplo que el usuario ha seleccionado 10 dias, entre el primero y el ultimo, lo intente con Carbon, y con createFormat y diffs, los propios metodos de php, pero todos me dan error de sintaxis digamos de la hora porque no esta correctamente formateada, y ya no se que mas probar, he debuggeado todas las variables y intentado formatearlas, pero no he sido capaz, os pongo los diferentes outputs que he ido viendo con dd, agradeceria una manita con esto.

Las funciones que he utilizado son estas, no las puse en el metodo porque me daba error todo el rato:

```
 $datetime1 = new DateTime($date[0]);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($date[1]);
    $interval= $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $days = $interval->format('dd-mm-yyyy');
```

Y la otra:

```
   $format = 'dd-mm-yyyy';
    $d1 = Carbon::createFromFormat($date[0],$format);
    $d2 = Carbon::createFromFormat($date[1],$format);
    //$days = $d1->diff($d2)->days;

    $daysTaken = $d2->diffInDays($d1);
```

Y el error este:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (27/08/2018 ) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

Y ahora lo que me parece mas redundante es que vuelvo a cambiar el formato para meterlo al objeto, y aparte quería ver la diferencia para saber cuantos días cogió y así calcular la diferencia, vi que se podía hacer en javascript, pero me tiraba los mismos errores.

Muchas gracias por su atención. Saludos.

Edito: fecha correctamente formateada como: "dd-mm-yyyy"

he utilizado tambien este metodo de carbon: que me arroja el siguiente error: 
Metodo:

```
$date  = explode('-',$request['datefilter']);
    $dateFrom = str_replace('/', '-', $date[0]);
    $dateTo = str_replace('/', '-', $date[1]);

    $start_date = Carbon::parse($date[0]);
    $end_date = Carbon::parse($date[1]);
    $diff = $start_date->diffInDays($end_date);
```

error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (22/08/2018 ) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

Edito2:

```
$date  = explode('-',$request['datefilter']);
    $dateFrom = str_replace('/', '-', $date[0]);
    $dateTo = str_replace('/', '-', $date[1]);
    $inicio = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date[0]);
    //echo $inicio->format('Y-m-d');
    $fin = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date[1]);
    dd($date[0]);
    //echo $fin->format('Y-m-d');
    $diff = date_diff($inicio, $fin);
    // Mostramos la diferencia
    dd($dif->format('%R%a días'));
```

Comment: has probado `date("d-m-Y",strtotime( $date[0]));
$dateTo = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($date[1]));` ?? creo que por eso el output te esta saliendo tan raro

Comment: y en `$format = 'dd-mm-yyyy';` lo mismo, cambiarlo por `$format = 'd-m-Y';`

Comment: perdon,  volviendolo a mirar la fecha te entra: 27/08/2018 y, por eso te esta sacando 01-01-1970. no lo acaba de leer del todo. Una solucion es que hagas `$dateFrom = str_replace('/', '-', $dateFrom);` y luego cambies los `'dd-mm-yyyy'` por `'d-m-Y'` Perdon por tanto comentario, es que estoy un tanto espeso. Dime si funciona.

Comment: Ahora mismo lo compruebo jeje, no pasa nada, gracias por tu aportacion

Comment: es que creo que es por el formato que entra la fecha mira [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937/strtotime-doesnt-work-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format).

Comment: Solucionado el problema de la fecha, sigo teniendo el problema de que tanto carbon, como el metodo diff de php, me siguen arrojando el error de formato, revisando las clases de carbon veo que usa "y-m-d" no se si tendra algo que ver

Comment: ostia, ahi ya no te puedo ayudar mucho mas. Carbon no lo controlo. PEro puedes probar el formato sea 'y-m-d'. igualmente acabo de buscar y mira `Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);` primero va el formato por lo que podrias probar como  
`$d1 = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date[0]);
$d2 = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $date[1]);`

Comment: creo que el problema que tengo es que como no tengo horas minutos segundos no lo interpreta bien, voy  a probar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No necesitas las horas ni minutos ni segundos. pero genial. Espero que haya sido de ayuda y que alguien mas te pueda ayudar :)

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez Respecto la ultima edicion, los `str_replace()` sobran, en todo caso añadir unos `trim()` para eliminar espacios como te indique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al no estar la fecha en el formato standard esperado necesitas parsearlo para que [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) lo intérprete correctamente. Para esto la clase `DateTime` nos proporciona el método `createFromFormat()`.

Veámos un ejemplo de uso:

```
$date[0] = "27/08/2018";
$date[1] = "28/08/2018";

$inicio = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', trim($date[0]));
echo $inicio->format('Y-m-d');

$fin = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', trim($date[1]));
echo $fin->format('Y-m-d');

// Diferencia de fechas 
$diff = date_diff($inicio, $fin);
// Mostramos la diferencia
echo $diff->format('%R%a días'); // +1 días
```

Documentación:

[DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php)

[DateTime::diff()](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Xerif, he probado lo que me comentas, y me arroja este error:         date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez  Acabo de probar el ejemplo tal cual lo puse y funciona. Por lo que indicas, alguna de la fechas no tiene el formato esperado, `createFromFormat` devuelve false en caso de que no pueda pasear la fecha. Revisa los datos que le pasas.

Comment: $inicio y $fin devuelven false, $date[0] devuelve " 22/08/2018", y $date[1] " 22/08/2018" con los espacios inclusive respectivamente. Edito2 la pregunta para que veas todo el codigo que tengo.

Comment: y aunque quite el replace, tambien me devuelven false. que se me olvidaba jeje

Comment: @DavidPazóLópez Seguramente es por culpa de los espacios, tienes 2 opciones hacerles un `trim()` creo que es lo mas adecuado `createFromFormat('d/m/Y',trim($date[0]));`  o añadir esos espacios al formato de `createFromFormat(' d/m/Y', $date[0]);` sinceramente prefiero lo primero. Pruebalo y me dices.

Comment: Muchas gracias xerif, me devuelve la diferencia de dias correctamente, y si, era por los espacios